# Show only selected month by year (YTD )

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

This is YTD sheet by all month in Tableau. I need to show only September 2020 and 2021. When I drag month(September) to filter then it shows false value. How can I do this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does your filter have to be dynamic? I mean if you open your dashboard today do you have to see October?

If yes you can simply create a calculated filed like

```
DATEPART('month', [MyDimensionDate])=DATEPART('month', TODAY())
```

and drag it to the filter panel, then select TRUE.